# ffmpeg 4 android_camera input options

Tags: ffmpeg, android

I have compiled ffmpeg 4.0 with android_camera support and packaged it into a simple app that allows to run it from the shell and acquire the necessary permissions.
I have some problems in passing android_camera private AVOptions (camera_index et al.) from the command line.

```
ffmpeg -f android_camera -fpsprobesize 0 -probesize 32 -rtbufsize 1M -c:v libx264 -g 30 -b:v 980k -r 30 -s 1280x720 -b:a 28k -ar 16000 -f mpegts udp://192.168.1.125:10000
```

Anyone can help?

---

Here is the full log

```
ffmpeg version 4.0 Copyright (c) 2000-2018 the FFmpeg developers
    progress:   built with gcc 4.9.x (GCC) 20150123 (prerelease)
  configuration: --prefix=/home/mschiavon/ffmpeg_android/builds --sysroot=/home/mschiavon/ffmpeg_android/android-toolchain-arm64/sysroot --cross-prefix=/home/mschiavon/ffmpeg_android/android-toolchain-arm64/bin/aarch64-linux-android- --target-os=linux --arch=arm64 --enable-cross-compile --enable-pic --disable-asm --disable-linux-perf --disable-doc --enable-gpl --enable-libx264 --disable-shared --enable-static --extra-cflags='-fPIE -DANDROID -DNDEBUG -I/home/mschiavon/ffmpeg_android/builds/include' --extra-ldflags='-pie -L/home/mschiavon/ffmpeg_android/builds/lib'
    progress:   libavutil      56. 14.100 / 56. 14.100
  libavcodec     58. 18.100 / 58. 18.100
    progress:   libavformat    58. 12.100 / 58. 12.100
    progress:   libavdevice    58.  3.100 / 58.  3.100
  libavfilter     7. 16.100 /  7. 16.100
    progress:   libswscale      5.  1.100 /  5.  1.100
  libswresample   3.  1.100 /  3.  1.100
  libpostproc    55.  1.100 / 55.  1.100
[android_camera @ 0x2023c9c600] Detected with id 0 disconnected.
[android_camera @ 0x2023c9c600] Android camera capture session is active.
```

Answer (score 1):

Your command should start like this (even though input string is irrelevant, it should be supplied).

```
-f android_camera camera_index 1 -fpsprobesize 0 -probesize 32 -rtbufsize 1M -i input ...
```

Comment: I have got it working with:
`-loglevel trace -f android_camera -camera_index 0 -video_size hd720 -framerate 30 -input_queue_size 2 -i discarded ...`

Comment: I have got it _kinda_ working with:

`ffmpeg -loglevel trace -f android_camera -camera_index 0 -video_size hd720 -framerate 30 -input_queue_size 2 -i discarded -map 0 -c copy /sdcard/output.raw`

now my problem is that ffmpeg seems stuck reading from camera. I am using an USB camera and the camera LED is turned on but no file is written.

Comment: Share full log - but not at trace level, verbose is fine.

Comment: @Gyan
I am not able to get camera_index working. I am able to stream from laptop's camera. But when I try to use a mobile camera as input, things start breaking. Can you please give a hand. I have a hunch that it has to do with ffmpeg version. But, not entirely sure.


Plesae find stack trace here : https://www.diffchecker.com/Mnnghg7M/